# Accessing array values from a Form in an ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the controlle,r I have this code:

```
var result = Request.Form[0];
```

where result has a value of `123,test,12,45,12/23/2010`...etc..

How can I store each value in one variable?

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you want to accomplish?

Comment: thanks David, now my result having the following (123,test,12,45,12/23/2010...etc..) now I need to sotre each value in one variable..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like "broken as designed," but:

```
string result = (string)Request.Form[0];
string []results = result.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do maybe try this-

```
string str =Request.Form[0].Select(c=>c.FormFieldName).ToString();
```

ideally you should get values using the id -

```
       string valueforid=Request.Form["Id"].Tostring();
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking to have each of those values stored in a variable. It's not clear, as the question is written, what your end goal is.

Consider simply accessing those values by their array position.

```
string[] myValues = Request.Form[0]
                              .ToString()
                              .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (string value in myValues)
{
    //do something

}
```

or

```
string customerID = myValues[0];
string customerName = myValues[1];
```